# Многопоточное чтение из бд

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Мне нужно одновременно выполнить два запроса к ms sql server(select'ы), если какой-либо поток
завершит работу раньше, он должен будет подождать до завершения работы второго. С многопоточностью особенно не сталкивался, подскажите,пожалуйста, как это реализовать. Мне даже не столько нужен готовый код, сколько сам алгоритм.

Comment: [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async). Ну и собственно `await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);` И здесь не нужны потоки, вообще. Задача суперпростая, вам нужно просто освоить технологию. Так как вопрос не содержит конкретики, ответить что-то конкретное так же сложно.

Comment: Простая для того, кто ее  уже освоил:)  Мне надо именно через два потока, задание такое. То есть у меня есть два textblock для вывода(делаю на wpf), необходимо в каждый записать результат запроса. И еще желательно(как я понял) добавить разную задержку, но вывод должен появиться одновременно, когда поздний поток закончит.

Comment: Нет конкретного вопроса - нет конкретного ответа. Покажите свой код, расскажите что именно не получается. Покажите текст задания, где про потоки написано.

Comment: Вот какой смысл от многопоточности если они должны ждать друг друга?

Comment: Чтобы был код я должен понять, что делать. А тут похоже не понимают даже те, кто варится в теме. Задание писал не я()

Comment: После того, как оба потока завершат работу, они должны будут вывести результаты своей работы. Поскольку БД небольшая и работа
потоков будет выполняться быстро, нужно
добавить в каждый запрос задержку в несколько секунд. Результаты должны выводиться, когда оба потока завершат работу. Если какой-либо поток
завершит работу раньше, он должен будет подождать до
завершения работы второго. Для запуска потоков используйте асинхронные делегаты.

Comment: WPF приложение с кнопкой «Start» и двумя текстовыми полями,в которые будет выводиться работа потоков.
 Кнопка Start должна запускать создание двух потоков. В одном потоке
должен выполняться запрос 1, во
втором запрос 2. Результаты  должны быть выведены в текстовые поля. 

Это все. Ну там еще есть мелкие детали, но они касаются обработки уже полученных данных.

Comment: Вы сначала сделайте синхронный код - выполнить один, потом выполнить второй, потом вывести результаты. Потом покажите код, который вы хотите с асинхронными делегатами выполнять. Обратите внимание на "асинхронными". Это с использованием ключевого слова `async`? Если да, то оно конфликтует с потоками, потому что не ни технического, не практического смысла спавнить поток для запуска такого делегата, ну разве что через `Task.Run`, и то сомнительное удовольствие, либо надо понять, что здесь значит слово "асинхронными". Но для начала напишите обычный синхронный код.

Comment: Чтобы обратиться к собеседнику в комментариях используйте собачку @Игорь, тогда собеседник получит уведомление о том, что вы ему написали. Упоминать собеседника не требуется только если он автор поста, под которым вы пишете комментарий.

Comment: Кстати, добавьте всю информацию из комментариев в сам вопрос, и метку `wpf`, если это WPF, вместе с вашим синхронным кодом.

Comment: Коллеги, а причём тут WPF? Общение с базой ведь всё равно в модели, и от используемого UI-фреймворка никак не зависит.

Comment: @VladD wpf вообще не причем, я просто его решил выбрать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из того, что я увидел в комментариях, можно написать следующий код (WPF)

```cs
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // подключение к бд
        Task<string> task1 = Task.Run(async () => // асинхронный делегат
        {
            // выполнение первого запроса
            string result = ...;
            await Task.Delay(1000); // ожидание, если надо
            return result;
        }
        Task<string> task2 = Task.Run(async () => 
        {
            // выполнение второго запроса
            string result = ...;
            await Task.Delay(500); // ожидание, если надо
            return result;
        }
        string[] results = await Task.WhenAll(new Task<string>[] { task1, task2 });
        TextBlock1.Text = results[0];
        TextBlock2.Text = results[1];
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Пока это всё что я могу вам предложить исходя из описания задачи

Comment: Есть почва для размышлений, спасибо

Comment: Спасибо, это именно то, что надо